# Analyze a tensorflow graph or a .pb file on Tensorboard

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

I have been following github repository for "Tensorflow on Android".

1. I was able to build the code using bazel and then import the Android project to Android Studio, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md).
2. As you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/build.gradle), after building the APK, using Android Studio, the Model files/Graphs are included in the `tensorflow/examples/android/assets`
3. By default, `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` and `imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt` are included, from inception5 file which is downloaded while the APK is built.

**What's the issue?**

1. I have a retrained graph (InceptionV3 model, mentioned in `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py`), which I was able to place in the assets folder in android directory and generate a working APK.
2. Inference time while I was using the default graph or .pb file was ~500ms and with my retrained.pb or graph it is ~1400ms.(tested on OnePlus3T device)

**Please help me understand**

1. How to analyze the default `tensorflow_inception_graph.pb` on Tensorboard

Comment: Is it because the `tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb` is stripped, optimized and quantized? Can someone please assert the statement?

Answer (score 7):

Last May they have introduced a helper script called [`import_pb_to_tensorboard`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) to do just that.

```
usage: import_pb_to_tensorboard.py [-h] [--model_dir MODEL_DIR]
                                   [--log_dir LOG_DIR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --model_dir MODEL_DIR
                        The location of the protobuf ('pb') model to
                        visualize.
  --log_dir LOG_DIR     The location for the Tensorboard log to begin
                        visualization from.
```

Note that currently, the version in `master` seems to have received more love than the one present in the latest `1.2.1` distribution of tensorflow, so I would suggest to use this one.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `import_pb_to_tensorboard.py` to work, so I opened this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11519